# Рефлексионное получение переменной типа Сlass массива модели из переменной типа Сlass модели

Tags: java, рефлексия

Всем доброго дня! Столкнулся с таким интересным вопросом при использовании рефлексии. Можно ли на Java каким-то способом реализовать такой метод:

```
private <T extends OdooModel> T[] parseRequest(Class<T> clazz) {
...
return new Gson().fromJson(model, clazz);//здесь неправильный аргумент clazz
}
```

Проблема состоит в том, что при вызове метода мне необходимо передать Model.class, а не Model[].class, в свою очередь для парсера нужно передать Model[].class. 
Т.е. по сути мы имеем переменную Class clazz = Model.class, из которой хотелось бы получить переменную Сlass clazz = Model[].class.

Спасибо

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679421/how-to-get-the-array-class-for-a-given-class-in-java

Comment: не по теме - среди всех прочих библиотек для работы с json, хочу особо отметить jackson, чего только он не умеет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Копирую два способа из ответа [@Christian Strempfer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/199048/christian-strempfer) на английском Stack Overflow ([How to get the Array Class for a given Class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679421/how-to-get-the-array-class-for-a-given-class-in-java):

1. Создать массив через [`Array.newInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance(java.lang.Class,%20int)) и получить его класс:

   ```
   Class arrayClass = Array.newInstance(clazz, 0).getClass();
   return new Gson().fromJson(model, arrayClass);
   ```
2. Сгенерировать название класса-массива и получить его по имени через [`Class.forName`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)):

   ```
   Class arrayClass = Class.forName("[L" + clazz.getCanonicalName() + ";");
   return new Gson().fromJson(model, arrayClass);
   ```

Более подробно можете почитать в статье [Java Reflection - Arrays](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/arrays.html) на jenkov.com.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Про получение по имени я думал, а вот создать инстанс как-то не сообразил))